# Barcode string value when using the Vision Framework of iOS11

Tags: swift, barcode, ios11, apple-vision

The following piece of Swift code is using the new iOS11 Vision framework to analyze an image and find QR codes within it.

```
let barcodeRequest = VNDetectBarcodesRequest(completionHandler {(request, error) in
    for result in request.results! {
        if let barcode = result as? VNBarcodeObservation {                    
            if let desc = barcode.barcodeDescriptor as? CIQRCodeDescriptor {
                let content = String(data: desc.errorCorrectedPayload, encoding: .isoLatin1)
                print(content) //Prints garbage
            }
        }
    }
}
let image = //some image with QR code...
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, options: [.properties : ""])
try handler.perform([barcodeRequest])
```

However, the problem is that the `desc.errorCorrectedPayload` returns the raw **[encoded data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Encoding)** as it has been read from the QR code.
In order to get a printable content string from the descriptor one must decode this raw data (e.g. determine the mode from the first 4 bits).

It gets even more interesting because Apple already has code for decoding raw data in the AVFoundation. The `AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject` class already has the `.stringValue` field which returns the **decoded** string.

Is it possible to access this decoding code and use it in Vision framework too?

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683242/vision-framework-barcode-detection-for-ios-11 ?

Comment: @nathan not dupe. The other one discuss overcoming an error message.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @swalkner See answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that now you can get a decoded string from a barcode using new [payloadStringValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnbarcodeobservation/2923485-payloadstringvalue) property of `VNBarcodeObservation` introduced in iOS 11 beta 5.

```
if let payload = barcodeObservation.payloadStringValue {
    print("payload is \(payload)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that it indeed returns the decoded string.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to, but all the barcodes are not being returned. From a label with 25 barcodes only 6 are being returned in the result :(

Comment: @appsmatics Did you ever figure this out? I'm encountering a similar issue where I can get it to highlight observed barcodes, but I can't get it to print the payload.

Comment: Unfortunately no :(