# Issue with CIQRCodeGenerator in CIFilter

Tags: ios, swift, ios12

I am updating existing app to support iOS 12 and strange issue with `CIFilter` appears.

This is simple class with one function `generate()`:

```
class QRGenerator {
    static func generate(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
        let context = CIContext()
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {
            filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 7, y: 7)
            if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform), let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

This class work perfectly until iOS 12. Now in line `if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")` I always receive nil.

I have spend some time on the Apple documentation but do not find any useful information about this issue.

Comment: I will appreciate if you explain why this question should be closed.

Comment: Replace data object line from below line.
let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know very little about `CIFilters`, but may be you could try to get all possible filter names:

```
let allFiltersNames = CIFilter.filterNames(inCategories: nil)
```

I couldn't spot one that matches `CIQRCodeGenerator` but may be there is some other filter with a different name that would meet your needs.

Comment: Do you think that is Apple bug? Because in the documentation we can see that this filter exists.

Comment: Do you have the documentation link ? Also check if it is for Xcode 10 documentation. You could file a bug report or Apple TSI to ask for more information on it.

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44683242/vision-framework-barcode-detection-for-ios-11 it is a custom solution

Comment: I know very little but I think `AVCapture` could be used https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-qr-code

Comment: This answer is about *scanning* a QR code while the question is about *generating* a QR code. Downvoted.

Comment: Hello @user1046037 this code causes the application to crash. xCode 11.4.1, iPhone 11, XR. But it's OK for all others iPhones.
Any idea? 
Do you think that with an earlier version of xCode it will work?

Comment: I am not so sure you could ask in Apple Dev Forums

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me too, I also tried generating the QR with an external library like QRcode https://github.com/aschuch/QRCode but the image of the QR is always nil.

It's nil when I install the app in emulators with iOS 12.0 (16A5308d) from Xcode 10.0 beta 2.

But when I install it in a physical device iPhone SE with iOS 12 beta 4 (16A5339e) from the same Xcode (10.0 beta 2), the QR is generated with no problem at all.

I also tried with an emulated iPhone SE with iOS 11.4 (15F79) from the same Xcode (10.0 beta 2) and works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5

```
class QRGenerator {
    static func generate(from string: String) -> UIImage? {
        let data = string.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
        filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        
        return UIImage(ciImage: (filter?.outputImage)!)
    }
}
```

**call this function**

> myImageView.image = QRGenerator.generate(from: "Stackoverflow")